# Using PugJS in Flask

Tags: python, flask, pug

Hej.

How to change template engine in flask?
I don't like Jinja, I want PugJS as my template engine.

Tried to google it but all I found was tutorials of Jinja.

Comment: I don't know PugJS but it seems it JavaScript template - so it will need to use also Node.js to render it. OR it may need to run directly in browser but Flask all render on server side.

Comment: PugJs is designed for Node, but It can be used on PHP or Django servers.
I hope it can also be used in Flask.

Comment: I'm not sure but Django may have built-in methods to use different templates (see [Support for template engines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines)) but `Flask` could be created to use only `Jinja` and you may have to write all code from scratch to replace `Jinja`. And PHP is not Web Framework so it can mess with everything.

Comment: someone wrote extension [Flask-Mako](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mako/) to use templates `Mako` and you can see its [source code](https://github.com/benselme/flask-mako/blob/master/flask_mako.py) to create own extension to replave `render_template()` with own code which will use `PugJS`. OR you should simply run `return your_renderer(...)` instead `return render_template(...)` and in `your_renderer(...)`  generate `HTML` using `PugJS` and use `return html` (PL: powodzenia)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyPugJS](https://github.com/kakulukia/pypugjs). I rewrited an [AdminLTE](https://github.com/kantium/AdminLTE-for-PugJS) template to PugJS some time ago for a demo app.